# Gnuplot (fitting of ellipse)

Tags: gnuplot, ellipse

I'm trying to fit an ellipse using gnuplot.

However, when I defined my equation

```
f(x,y) = a*x*x + b*x*y + c*y*y + d*x + e*y + f
```

and then proceed with the command plot:

```
plot f(x,y) lw 3 lc rgb 'black', 'text.dat' w l lc rgb 'black'
```

I get `undefined variable: y`. How can I fix it?
`text.dat` has 3 columns: x, y, and z coordinates.

Comment: you should have a look to `parametric mode` : http://www.gnuplotting.org/understand-parametric-plotting or http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.0/param.html

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate the problem, let's assume that the data points to be fitted are stored in file `pnts.dat` (x,y coordinates):

```
-2.000000   -0.005494
-1.789474   -0.410310
-1.578947   -0.616013
-1.368421   0.760577
-1.157895   0.695609
-0.947368   0.921957
-0.736842   -0.882355
-0.526316   -1.031450
-0.315789   -0.910362
-0.105263   -0.986339
0.105263    -0.897862
0.315789    -1.059766
0.526316    -1.007012
0.736842    0.910494
0.947368    -0.878432
1.157895    0.823232
1.368421    0.831900
1.578947    -0.662069
1.789474    0.427903
2.000000    -0.001474
```

Now, the goal is to find the optimal values of the parameters in the equation `a*x*x + b*x*y + c*y*y + d*x + e*y + f = 0`. However, if this equation is used directly in the fitting procedure, the result will be most likely that all parameters are equal zero since then it is satisfied automatically for any values of x,y. In case one is interested in a non-degenerate ellipse, it must hold that `b*b-4*a*c<0`. Therefore, the parameter `a` can't be zero and it is thus possible to impose the condition `a=1`.

As for the fitting itself, the script below proceeds in several steps:

1. the fit is performed using the `fit` command specifying the remaining parameters `b,c,d,e,f`
2. to generate then the plot of the implicit function `f(x,y(x))=0`, it uses a "trick" with `splot` to get a contour corresponding to the value of 0. The calculated points are stored to a file `contour.dat` via the `set table` command.
3. this contour is then plotted together with the original points

In total:

```
f(x, y) = x*x + b*x*y + c*y*y + d*x + e*y + f
fit f(x, y) 'pnts.dat' u 1:2:(0) via b,c,d,e,f

set contour
set view map
unset surface
set cntrparam levels discrete 0
set isosamples 1000,1000

set table 'contour.dat'
splot f(x, y)

unset table
unset contour

set terminal pngcairo enhanced
set output 'fig.png'

set xr [-3:3]
set yr [-3:3]
set size square

plot \
    'contour.dat' u 1:2 w l lw 2 lc rgb 'red', \
    'pnts.dat' u 1:2 w p ps 1.5 lc rgb 'black'
```

This then produces:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey there, do I need an extra column for the z axis? Every time I tried plot, it gives "z axis range undefined". In addition, it seems that I didn't read the values in correctly because I kept getting -nan and -inf values when use the fit command. Any thoughts? Thanks!